# How to I search the database and output the result in datagridview?

Tags: c#, database

For example , I have this Name in the database:

Leo

Jerry

Bruce

Apple

If I type in the letter in the textBox 'e' it will automatically(without Button) show all the name that contain the letter 'e', but when i type "eo" then it only show the Name "Leo"

Have you ever tried the shortcut Control + F(search) in the keyboard??

I want to do something similar to that but it is in datagridview and textBox.

If you dont understand what i am asking then you can try the Control + F in the keyboard and find out what i mean

Here is my code that work with button and textBox

```
       private void Search_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Co-op\Contact\Contact\ContactDataBase.sdf;Password=********");
        con.Open();
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select * from Contact_List;", con);

        try
        {
            SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.Filter = "[Name]=" + "'" + Search_Box.Text + "'";
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            sda.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look up controls for "AutoComplete textbox" and the like - these controls are similar to the functionality you're describing.  Generally they work off of ajax calls and/or an in memory store of possible values

Comment: You need a SQL with a Where clause containing a 'LIKE' : Where Contact Like '%abc%'.  Notice the single quotes.  The percent signs are wild cards.

Comment: I don't get it, can you show me the code?